# Choosing Rabbonim in shtetlach

Tags: history, rabbis

How were Rabbonim chosen in Shetlach?

Was there an Election (like in Crown Heights), and if so, who were eligible to vote? 
Was it all men were allowed, or just learned members of the community?

Comment: I imagine it was different between western and eastern europe, as well as between chasidic groups and non-chasidic groups. Which time period are you curious about? which part of Europe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I have read. Often there were 2-3 people selected that would decide on a Rav. They would then go and present a K'sav Rabbonus - an official letter requesting that this individual selected should come and be the Rav in their town.